# Why is my neural network stagnating around a certain cost?

Tags: c++, neural-network, backpropagation, mnist, feed-forward

I am making a neural network that's supposed to be capable of identifying handwritten numbers using the Mnist database [downloadable here](http://makeyourownneuralnetwork.blogspot.com/2015/03/the-mnist-dataset-of-handwitten-digits.html). The network works perfectly with one to 5 examples but after 10 it starts to get a bit iffy. Using a standard of 5000 examples the program will stagnate at around 0.42 cost (it starts at around 1.2 costs). all the output of the 10 neurons in the last layer will also trend towards 0.1 and the network is noticeably never very certain of it's guess because of this (usually the output of the guess will be around 0.1 to 0.2 with some exceptions)

Example of guess and outputs of the last layer after training for 5000 iterations:

```
Example:        5000
index:  2435
Cost:   0.459006
Expected:      0

Out_value 0:    0.0900279
Out_value 1:    0.104657
Out_value 2:    0.0980369
Out_value 3:    0.0990471
Out_value 4:    0.101716
Out_value 5:    0.0937537
Out_value 6:    0.0933432
Out_value 7:    0.114351
Out_value 8:    0.10058
Out_value 9:    0.0924466
Guess:  7
Guess certainty:        0.114351

false
```

I've tried adjusting the number and size of the h-layers and the learning rate, but the result is always the same (constantly jumping around a cost of around 0.42). I, of course, theorized that my backprop or math just didn't check out, but testing this with a test network based on a guide on backprop, [link here](https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/) my weights adjusted themselves perfect to the decimal according to the article. So I'm not sure what to do to prevent my network from stagnating and to make it learn at this point. Does anyone have any idea why it might be stagnating like this?

Relevant code in the cpp-file for the neural network:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
#include <utility>
#include "neural_network.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

namespace nn{
    double fRand(const double& f_min, const double& f_max){ //generate random double from f_min to f_max
        const auto f = static_cast<double>(rand()) / RAND_MAX;
        return f_min + f * (f_max - f_min);
    }
    double sigmoid(const double& net) { //sigmoid function for out value
        const double result = 1.0 / static_cast<double>(1.0 + pow(M_E, -net));
        return result;
    }
    double xavier(int layer_from_size) {    //function used to initialize initial weights.
        const double val = sqrt(1.0 / static_cast<double>(layer_from_size));
        return val;
    }

    double out_net_derivative(const double& out){ //derviative of out-value with respect to the net-value
        const double val = out * (1 - out);
        return val;
    }
    double cost_out_derivative(const double& out, const double& target)
        //derivative of the cost with respect to the out-value for the neurons in the last layer
    { 
        const double val = out - target;
        return val;
    }
    double calc_cost(const Layer& layer, std::vector<double> target){ //calculating the total cost mainly for logging
        double cost = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < target.size(); i++){
            cost += pow(target[i] - layer.get_neurons()[i].get_out(), 2) / 2;
        }
        return cost;
    }
    double delta(const double& cost_out_derivative, const double& out)
        //derivative of the cost with respect to the current neurons out multiplied by out_net_derivative
    {
        const double val = cost_out_derivative * out_net_derivative(out);
        return val;
    }

    Weight::Weight(double weight, int neuron_from_index)
        :weight_{ weight }, neuron_from_index_{ neuron_from_index }
    {}

    Neuron::Neuron(int pos, int layer) //creating a empty neuron
        : net_{ 0.0 }, out_{ 0.0 }, error_gradient_{ 0.0 }, pos_{ pos }, layer_{ layer }
    {
    }
    Neuron::Neuron(int pos, double out) //creating a neuron in the first layer with a pre-assigned out-value
        : net_{ 0.0 }, out_{ out }, error_gradient_{ 0.0 }, pos_{ pos }, layer_{ 0 }
    {
    }

    void Neuron::update_weights(const Layer& layer_from, const double& learning_rate){
        for (Weight& weight : weights_to_) {
            //derivative of net with respect to weight
            double neuron_from_out = layer_from.get_neurons()[weight.get_neuron_from_index()].get_out();
            //derivative of cost with respect to weight
            double val = delta(error_gradient_, out_) * neuron_from_out;
            weight.update_weight(val, learning_rate);
        }
    }

    void Layer::update_error_gradient(Layer& layer_from)
        //update all the error gradients (derivative of the cost with respect to the neurons out-value) in the previous layer (layer_from)
    {
        for (Neuron& neuron : layer_from.neurons_) neuron.set_error_gradient(0); //resetting all previous error gradients
        for (int i = 0; i < neurons_.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < layer_from.get_neurons().size(); j++) {
                double delta_val = delta(neurons_[i].get_error_gradient(), neurons_[i].get_out());
                //partial derivative of cost with respect to the last layers neuron in position j
                double val = neurons_[i].get_weights_to()[j].get_weight() * delta_val;
                layer_from.neurons_[j].update_error_gradient(val);
            }
        }
    }
    void Layer::update_bias(const double& learning_rate){
        for(const Neuron& neuron: neurons_){
            //derivative of the cost with respect to the layer-bias
            double val = out_net_derivative(neuron.get_out()) * neuron.get_error_gradient();
            bias_ -= learning_rate * val;
        }
    }

    void Neuron::set_weights(const int& layer_from_size){ //set initial weights for neuron
        for(int i = 0; i < layer_from_size; i++){
            //get random weight using xavier weight initialization
            double v_val = fRand(-xavier(layer_from_size), xavier(layer_from_size));
            Weight weight{ v_val, i };

            weights_to_.push_back(weight);  
        }
    }

    void Layer::set_weights(const int& layer_from_size){ //set initial weights for layer
        for (Neuron& neuron : neurons_) neuron.set_weights(layer_from_size);
    }
    void Network::set_weights(){ //set initial weights for network
        //srand(time(NULL));
        for(int i = 1; i < layers_.size(); i++){
            layers_[i].set_weights(layers_[i - 1].get_neurons().size());
        }
    }
    Layer::Layer(int pos, int size) //make layer of any size
        : pos_{ pos }, bias_{ 0.0 }
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //fill with neurons according to desired size
        {
            Neuron neuron{ i, pos };
            neurons_.push_back(neuron);
        }
    }

    Layer::Layer(std::vector<Neuron> first_layer) //set the first layer of the network according pre-acquired neurons
        :pos_{ 0 }, bias_{ 0.0 }, neurons_{std::move(first_layer)}
    {}

    void Layer::forward_pass(const Layer& layer_from){ //calculate net, and out-value of each neuron in layer
        for(Neuron& neuron : neurons_){
            double val = calc_net(layer_from, neuron, bias_);
            neuron.set_net(val);
            neuron.set_out(sigmoid(val));
        }
    }
    void Network::forward_pass(){ //calculate net, and out-value of each neuron in network
        for (int i = 1; i < layers_.size(); i++)
            layers_[i].forward_pass(layers_[i - 1]);
    }

    void Layer::backprop(const Layer& layer_from, const double& learning_rate){ //backprop and thus update weights in layer
        for (Neuron& neuron : neurons_) 
            neuron.update_weights(layer_from, learning_rate);
    }
    void Network::backprop(const std::vector<double>& target){ //backprop entire network and thus update weights and biases
        forward_pass();
        set_last_layer_error_grads(target);
        for(int i = layers_.size() - 1; i > 0; i--){
            //update error gradients for the previous layer in the network
            layers_[i].update_error_gradient(layers_[i - 1]);
            layers_[i].backprop(layers_[i - 1], learning_rate_);
            layers_[i].update_bias(learning_rate_);
        }
    }

    Network::Network(std::vector<int> structure, double learning_rate) //create a network skeleton
        :learning_rate_{learning_rate}
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < structure.size(); i++){ //fill network with layers of various sizes according to structure
            Layer layer{ i, structure[i] };
            layers_.push_back(layer);
        }
    }

    void Network::set_last_layer_error_grads(std::vector<double> target){
        for (int i = 0; i < layers_[layers_.size() - 1].get_neurons().size(); i++) {
            double val = cost_out_derivative(layers_[layers_.size() - 1].get_neurons()[i].get_out(), target[i]);
            layers_[layers_.size() - 1].set_neuron_error_grad(i, val);
        }
    }

    int Network::get_guess() const{ //get the networks guess for each example (image)
        int guess = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < layers_[layers_.size() - 1].get_neurons().size(); i++) {
            if (layers_[layers_.size() - 1].get_neurons()[guess].get_out() < layers_[layers_.size() - 1].get_neurons()[i].get_out())
                guess = i;
            //std::cout << "Guess certainty " << i << ":\t" << layers[layers.size() - 1].get_neurons()[i].get_out_value() << '\n';
            std::cout << "Out_value " << i << ":\t" << layers_[layers_.size() - 1].get_neurons()[i].get_out() << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << "Guess:\t" << guess << '\n'
            << "Guess certainty:\t" << layers_[layers_.size() - 1].get_neurons()[guess].get_out() << "\n\n";
        return guess;
    }

    int Network::get_weight_amount() const //get number of weights
    {
        int amount = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < layers_.size(); i++) {
            amount += layers_[i - 1].get_neurons().size() * layers_[i].get_neurons().size();
        }
        return  amount;
    }

    double calc_net(const Layer& layer_from, const Neuron& neuron, const double& bias){ // calculate net-value for specific neuron
        const std::vector<Neuron>& neurons_from = layer_from.get_neurons();
        const std::vector<Weight>& weights = neuron.get_weights_to();

        if (neurons_from.size() != weights.size()) 
            throw std::exception("there is not strictly one weight for each neuron in layer from.");

        double net = 0;
        //calculate net value with respect to the previous layers neurons and weights connecting them
        for (int i = 0; i < neurons_from.size(); i++)
            net += neurons_from[i].get_out() * weights[i].get_weight(); 
        net += bias;

        return net;
    }

    void Network::train(std::ifstream& practice_file, const int& sample_size, const int& practise_loops)
        //train network with a specific sample size a specific number of times according to practice loops,
        //getting necessary data for the first layer from a practice file
    {
        //srand(time(NULL));

        std::vector<Layer> images;
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> targets;
        for(int i = 0; i < sample_size; i++){ //get and store all images and targets for the images in different vectors
            std::vector<double> image = get_image(practice_file);
            images.push_back(get_flayer(image));
            targets.push_back(get_target(image, layers_[layers_.size() - 1].get_neurons().size()));
        }
        //backprop through random examples taken from the sample
        for(int i = 0; i < practise_loops; i++){
            int index = rand() % images.size();

            layers_[0] = images[index];
            backprop(targets[index]);

            std::cout << "Example:\t" << i << '\n' <<   //logging
                "index:\t" << index << '\n'
                << "Cost:\t" << calc_cost(layers_[layers_.size() - 1], targets[index]) << '\n';
            if (correct_guess(targets[index]))
                std::cout << "true\n";
            else std::cout << "false\n";

        }
    }
    double Network::test(std::ifstream& test_file, const int& sample_size){ //test network accuracy
        int correct = 0;
        std::vector<Layer> images;
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> targets;
        for (int i = 0; i < sample_size; i++) {
            std::vector<double> image = get_image(test_file);
            images.push_back(get_flayer(image));
            targets.push_back(get_target(image, layers_[layers_.size() - 1].get_neurons().size()));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < sample_size; i++)
        {
            layers_[0] = images[i];
            forward_pass();
            if (correct_guess(targets[i])) correct++; //keep track of correct guesses
        }

        double accuracy = 100 * correct / sample_size; //calculate accuracy
        return accuracy;
    }
    std::vector<double> get_image(std::ifstream& ifs) { //get an image data from a file (specifically from the mnist files
        std::vector<double> values; //all data converted to relevant format
        std::string value; //data in string format
        std::string line; //all data in string format
        std::getline(ifs, line); //get image
        //convert image string to relevant grey scale and target doubles and store them to be returned
        for (const char& ch : line) {
            switch (ch) {
            case '0': case '1':
            case '2': case '3':
            case '4': case '5':
            case '6': case '7':
            case '8': case '9':
            case '.':
                value += ch;
                break;
            default:
                values.push_back(std::stod(value));
                value.clear();
                break;
            }
        }
        values.push_back(std::stod(value)); //store last piece of data
        return values;
    }
    std::vector<double> get_target(const std::vector<double>& image, int last_layer_size){ //get target for an image
        std::vector<double> target(last_layer_size);
        //make sure that every neuron that is not the correct answer isn't lit up and do the opposite for the correct answer neuron
        for(int i = 0; i < last_layer_size; i++){
            //according to the file setup the first piece of data in the image is the target, hence image[0]
            if (i == static_cast<int>(image[0])) target[i] = 1.0; //0.99
        }
        return target;
    }

    Layer get_flayer(std::vector<double> image) { //get the first layer through image
        std::vector<Neuron> neurons;
        image.erase(image.begin()); //throw away the target
        for (int i = 0; i < image.size(); i++) {
            Neuron neuron{ i, image[i] };
            neurons.push_back(neuron);
        }
        Layer layer{ neurons };
        return layer;
    }
    bool Network::correct_guess( const std::vector<double>& target) const{ //confirm if a guess by the network is correct
        int excpected = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < target.size(); i++)
            if (target[i] == 1.0) excpected = i; //the correct guess is the neuron position of the neuron fully lit of the bunch
        std::cout << "Excpected:\t" << excpected << "\n\n";
        return excpected == get_guess();
    }
}
```

Link to full code including some exta functions in cpp-file, h-file, and main-file on GitHub for more context: [Full code](https://github.com/Eathus/Neural-Network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that the mistake I had made was related to how I read the greyscale values (the input) from the CSV-file containing the Mnist images converted to greyscale. I had neglected to divide each greyscale value with 255 (the highest possible greyscale value) to convert the greyscale to values between 0 and 1. Because of this, the second layer received huge input values thus causing the outputs of the second layer to explode massively. I have now fixed this issue and the program has around 87% accuracy when training with a file batch of 5000 images after 10000 iterations with one h-layer of size 16 (layer sizes: 784, 16, 10). While still not being optimal it is, of course, a huge improvement.